# Post json-data from my own dojo-widget

Tags: json, dojo

I build my own widget with dojo as discussed here: [Custom Widget](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/recipes/custom_widget/)

Now, I want to post the data on a certain event with the following code:

```js
xhr.post({
  handleAs: "json",
  form: "answerForm",
  timeout: 15000,
  load: lang.hitch(this, "_onSubmitted", button),
  error: lang.hitch(this, "_onSubmitError", button)
});
```

I expected something like this in my xhr.post `content: dojo.toJson(this)`

How can I sent the data in json format to the server?
Thanks!

Edit: added html-template

```
<form id="answerForm" action="${url}">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="selectionAnswerWidget" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'bottom'">

        <div data-dojo-type="dojo.store.Memory" data-dojo-id="answerStore"
            data-dojo-props="data: [{id: 'YES', name: 'yes'}, {id: 'NO', name: 'no'}, {id: 'UNANSWERED', name: 'unanswered'}]"></div>
        <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" value="${answer}"
            data-dojo-props="store:answerStore, searchAttr:'name'" data-dojo-attach-point="answerSelection" />
    </div>

    <div data-dojo-attach-point="textAreaAnswerWidget" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">

        <textarea data-dojo-attach-point="commentNode" rows="5" cols="50" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea"
            data-dojo-props="selectOnClick:true">${comment}</textarea>
    </div>
```

The data is correct in the html and the post arrives at the server but without the data.

Comment: I corrected my `data-dojo-attach-point`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use postData in your xhrArgs.

```
xhr.post({
 handleAs: "json",
 postData:  dojo.toJson(obj),
 timeout: 15000,
 load: lang.hitch(this, "_onSubmitted", button),
 error: lang.hitch(this, "_onSubmitError", button)
});
```

Comment: with postData I would have to recreate the same object with which I loaded my widget. Do you know why the `form: "answerForm"` doesn't work. The data is there

Comment: The focus of my answer may have been incorrect.  Your problem is that when you post, the data from your widget is not in the post parameters?  Does your custom widget have an html input field?  Posting the form, is going to look for html input fields for the data.

Comment: I added the html-template (see above). Yes, there are no data in the post

Comment: I solved the problem with writing the object myself to the post: `content = {
                        answer: this.answer,
                        comment: this.comment.getValue()
                    }`